# How to validation of Excel file location is valid or not

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, validation

I am trying that print dynamic value into the .xlsx file. I am trying that
print of that.

```
worksheet.write("A13","Hello")
```

But I am trying that user is given the location and value just like

```
location = ("A13")
value = ("Hello")
self.get_value_location(location, value, worksheet)


def get_value_location(location,value,worksheet):
  worksheet.write(location,value)
```

So, my question how to validation given that location is proper in the .xlsx file

Comment: Which programming language is that? Please add the proper tags to your question.

Comment: Place the function before its call.